# Why is my rails controller rolling back my ajax commit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having a mysterious problem with the controller receiving my ajax request but not saving it in the database. In my server log I see:

```
Started POST "/collection_maps" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-07 07:14:04 -0600
Processing by CollectionMapsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"collection_id"=>"2", "manufacturer_id"=>"1", "package_id"=>"14"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendered collection_maps/create.js.erb (1.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 19.2ms (Views: 4.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2014 07:14:04] "POST /collection_maps HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0627
```

The response I receive in the browser from my create.js.erb file indicates the parameters are null -- but as you can see above, they're clearly there.
(The response comes only as text, the browser doesn't execute the code, but that's another problem. I think.)

```
// Create a list of errors
var errors = $('<ul />');

errors.append('<li>Package can\&#x27;t be blank</li>');
errors.append('<li>Manufacturer can\&#x27;t be blank</li>');
errors.append('<li>Collection can\&#x27;t be blank</li>');

// Display errors on form
$("#collection-response").html(errors).show();
```

When I try to create the record in the console, using the same parameters, it works:

```
irb(main):006:0> c = CollectionMap.new("collection_id"=>"2", "manufacturer_id"=>"1", "package_id"=>"12")
=> #<CollectionMap id: nil, package_id: 12, manufacturer_id: 1, collection_id: 2, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):007:0> c.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (5.7ms)  INSERT INTO "collection_maps" ("collection_id", "created_at", "package_id", "manufacturer_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["collection_id", 2], ["created_at", Mon, 07 Jul 2014 06:38:47 UTC +00:00], ["package_id", 12], ["manufacturer_id", 1], ["updated_at", Mon, 07 Jul 2014 06:38:47 UTC +00:00]]
   (1.2ms)  commit transaction
=> true
irb(main):008:0> c
=> #<CollectionMap id: 6, package_id: 12, manufacturer_id: 1, collection_id: 2, created_at: "2014-07-07 06:38:47", updated_at: "2014-07-07 06:38:47">
```

I thought maybe it had something to do with CRSF protection (though I don't have user sessions) so I added a `skip_filter`. Here's my controller code:

```
class CollectionMapsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :js, :html
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
  # POST /collection_maps
  # POST /collection_maps.xml
  def create
    @collection_map = CollectionMap.new(params[:collection_map])
    flash[:notice] = "Collection map successfully added" if @collection_map.save
    respond_with( @collection_map,  :layout => !request.xhr?)
  end
```

Here's my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({ url: '<%="#{collection_maps_path}"%>',
         type: 'POST',
         beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token',
                                                         '<%="#{form_authenticity_token}"%>')},
         dataType: "js",
         data: {'collection_id' : this.value, 
                'manufacturer_id' : $("#remedy_manufacturer_id option:selected").val(),
                'package_id' : $("#remedy_package_id option:selected").val()},
       });
```

And finally, my model:

```
class CollectionMap < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :manufacturer
  belongs_to :package
  belongs_to :collection
  validates_presence_of :package_id, :manufacturer_id, :collection_id
  attr_protected :created_at
  attr_protected :updated_at
  attr_accessible :package_id, :manufacturer_id, :collection_id
end
```

I am totally baffled, so help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE: The reason my browser was not executing the javascript returned by the controller was because I had `dataType: "js"` in the ajax request. Should be `dataType: "script"`. Be careful where you cut and paste from!

Comment: It's certainly a validation issue. Insert `pp @collection_map.errors` just before the `respond_with` line in your create action, and check in your server console you will find your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AJAX request is sending back the three parameters you need, but your controller action is looking for them nested below a `:collection_map` key. You can change your controller to this:

```
def create
    @collection_map = CollectionMap.new(params)
    flash[:notice] = "Collection map successfully added" if @collection_map.save
    respond_with( @collection_map,  :layout => !request.xhr?)
end
```

Or change your AJAX request to this:

```
$.ajax({ url: '<%="#{collection_maps_path}"%>',
         type: 'POST',
         beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token',
                                                         '<%="#{form_authenticity_token}"%>')},
         dataType: "js",
         data: {'collection_map': {'collection_id' : this.value, 
                'manufacturer_id' : $("#remedy_manufacturer_id option:selected").val(),
                'package_id' : $("#remedy_package_id option:selected").val()}},
       });
```

Changing the AJAX request is probably preferable; nesting the parameters below a single key is more "Rails-like"/idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

you are also mixing `attr_accessible` and `attr_protected`. Choose One. Or if this is a newer Rails (4.0 + ) project, use the the new params methodology by creating a method like 'collection_map_params' for 'protection' in your `CollectioMapsController`.

Comment: This wasn't the cause of the issue, but it's nonetheless helpful advice. Thanks!